# systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/stonedb.service:4] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Unit'

Tags: mariadb, systemctl

I have created a custom service but when I try to check the status of it then I get this errors:

```
[root@stonedb system]# systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl status stonedb -l
● stonedb.service - StoneDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/stonedb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2023-10-11 18:53:03 CEST; 5 days ago
 Main PID: 23915 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 11 18:53:03 stonedb.reporting systemd[1]: stonedb.service failed.
Oct 12 00:18:57 stonedb.reporting systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/stonedb.service:4] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Unit'
Oct 12 00:38:17 stonedb.reporting systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/stonedb.service:4] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Unit'
Oct 12 01:53:15 stonedb.reporting systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/stonedb.service:4] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Unit'
Oct 12 02:07:40 stonedb.reporting systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/stonedb.service:4] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Unit'
Oct 12 02:14:26 stonedb.reporting systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/stonedb.service:4] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Unit'
Oct 12 02:18:23 stonedb.reporting systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/stonedb.service:34] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Service'
Oct 12 02:19:13 stonedb.reporting systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/stonedb.service:30] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Unit'
Oct 17 01:24:37 stonedb.reporting systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/stonedb.service:4] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitInterval' in section 'Unit'
Oct 17 01:27:18 stonedb.reporting systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/stonedb.service:11] Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitIntervalSec' in section 'Service'
```

Even I didn't set any directive named `StartLimitIntervalSec` or `StartLimitInterval` but still report it as I did.

Here is my service content:

```
[Unit]
Description=StoneDB database server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
ExecStart=/opt/stonedb57/install/mysql_server
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Current systemctl version:

```
[root@stonedb system]# systemctl --version
systemd 219
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: To whom vote for closing it, can you at least explain why?

Comment: What does the close reason say? "Not about programming or software development"

Comment: From [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463917/ddg#464098), `StartLimitIntervalSec` was added in v230. You are on and older version.

Comment: @danblack But I didn't `StartLimitIntervalSec` at all.